# Populate text field with Value of selected option in Select list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do this with javascript.  I have an onchange event for the select list calling a javascript function.  The Javascript never gets ran as I have changed the function to just a simple alert and it never pops up.  Anything obviously wrong with this?

HTML

```
select name="nSupervisor" id="iSupervisor" onchange="PopulateUserName()">
        <option value="">---------- </option>
        <option value="test1">Actual Text</option>
    </select>  
<input id="iSupervisorUserName" name="OBKey_WF_Manger_Supervisor_1" type="text" />
```

JavaScript

```
function PopulateUsername() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("iSupervisor");
    var field = document.getElementByID("iSupervisorName");
    field.value = dropdown.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few errors on your code there.

First, make sure `function PopulateUsername()` isn't wrapped by some other function. For now, I assume its not.

Second, JavaScript is case sensitive, so you're calling `PopulateUserName()` which is NOT `PopulateUsername()`.

Third, you're going to run into an error when you try `var field = document.getElementByID(`, as it should be `getElementById` <-- lowercase 'd'.

After that, it should work, and place the value ("test1") into your text box.

JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/LrCwK/2/

Comment: All these problems should be reported in the Javascript console.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it,

```
function PopulateUsername() {
    var sup = document.getElementById("iSupervisor");
    var field = document.getElementById("iSupervisorName");
    field.value = sup.options[sup.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the correction.  I'm still having a problem where the function isn't getting called.  As I understand as soon as the select list loses focus, the onchange event should get called, but nothing ever happens.....

Comment: you have a typo in the function name.. its `PopulateUserName` not `PopulateUsername` :P